# Change method suggestion color in Codeium for Jetbrains

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I use the high contrast theme, the background is black and so is the Codeium help text. Is there any way to change the color of the recommendations?

I looked through all of the settings for the codeium plugin in jetbrains, but found nothing color related.

[image]